# How to change from derby to MySQL in Spark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

I have installed a spark 2.4.7 using "spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz"
I could see the metastore_db got created automatically under the usr home directory and it contains derby database. Also when I developer runs a query it throws error like below

```
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@6cde460, see the next exception for details.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:361)
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
```

we are not planning to use derby database, I have MySQL database ready on a different host, can some one please help me understand how can I change the config to point my spark to MySQL instead of the derby??

Thanks in advance

Suresh